# No login - Fat Client - Ubuntu Server

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, login

I want to build an Ubuntu Server that distributes images to clients over the network.
Clients must behave like Fat Client (Processing on the server instead of client).

All computers that enter in the network must have the same user (and it needs to login automatically).
I Know it's possible with Thin Client but i don't know if it is possible with Fat Client.

Comment: What is an "image"? What processing? Please explain more clearly.

Comment: Image (ISO)  = OS(Operating System).
The  Processing needed for the users task